# Laravel - Do not use .env file at all

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables

It's more like a question without knowledge of new versions of Laravel, but it's possible to not use .env file at all in Laravel Framework?

I used the `config:cache` to not require .env files do cache the config, but to read directly from the system.

Comment: You *could* just set all of your variables right in the config files, since anything that grabs the .env value also has a default value, such as `'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1')`. But it really isn't recommended, since if you use something like git, the config files are stored but the .env file is excluded, thus preventing credentials being exposed.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/configuration#environment-configuration also points out that it's good for when you have different values/credentials for different environments.

Comment: If you don't want to use a `.env` file, that's fine; simply replace any instances of `env(...)` in the various `config/*.php` files with hard-coded values, but you might run into issues, especially if you try to use packages that require a `.env` file. There are security issues, but that only really matters if you plan on making this a publicly available application.

Comment: @TimLewis Thank you, the ideia was not hardcode the values at all, just checking if the .env is mandatory to exists in a Laravel installation.

Comment: I will checkout the vlucas/phpdotenv requirements, in my opnion .env files are great for devs but should not exists in production environments

Comment: No you don't need .env file.  Advice to hard code the values into config should be taken with caution as you don't want to be securing any of your secrets in your code repository.  The best solution is to create ACTUAL environment variables.... but I guess this is not why you are asking.  You are trying to solve some other issue that you have not mentioned???

Comment: Gotcha. So, by default, Laravel doesn't have a `.env` file, just a `.env.example`, which is converted to `.env` on initial setup. This is done to connect the various `config/*.php` files to the `.env` file via `'setting' => env('SETTING')`. If you simply replace all of those with hard-coded values, like `'setting' => 'setting'`, then you _should_ be able to run without a `.env` file. Easiest way to test this is to try it and see what happens; if your Laravel app runs, then you've answered your own question.

Comment: @Snapey thats exacly why i'm trying to check out, i'm using env variables from my system, but the existence of the .env file as mandatory was a little doubt i had

Comment: you dont need to hard code anything .... just set real environmental variables ... `.env` is just a means to not have to set "real" environmental variables

Comment: The name `.env` comes from "environment". I'm not a Laravel user but frameworks don't typically care about where the environment values come from: you can set them from the web server, from a configuration server...